# how to use fadeIn() for a single row when appended to a table

Tags: jquery, ajax, web

my goal is to call fadeIn() function on a single row of a table when that row is appended to the table.

I have problem with the below code. It fades out entire table.

```
$.get("/getItems/"+count, function(data){
            tr="<tr> <div>";
            td1="<td>"+data["ID"]+"</td>";
            td2="<td>"+data["UNITID"]+"</td>";
            td3="<td>"+data["INSTNM"]+"</td>";
            td4="<td>"+data["ADDR"]+"</td>";
            td5="<td>"+data["CITY"]+"</td>";
            td6="<td>"+data["STABBR"]+"</td>";
            td7="<td>"+data["ZIP"]+"</td><div></tr>";
            $("#table1").append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4+td5+td6+td7);


           (tr.find(div)).fadeIn(300);

            var rowCount = $('#table1 tr').length;  
            console.log(rowCount);

            if(rowCount>20)
            {
                removeFirstRowAndAppendNewItem(data)
            }
            function removeFirstRowAndAppendNewItem(data)
            {
              console.log("in callback"); // to confirm we have reached here
              $("table#table1 tr:nth-child(2)").remove();}});
```

**Any idea why entire table is getting updated rather than one single row?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fadeIn the first row in table

```
$('table#table1 > tr:first').hide().fadeIn(300);
```

or

```
$('table#table1 > tr').first().hide().fadeIn(300);
```

and about your code you can make it like this

```
        tr ="<tr> <div>";
        tr +="<td>"+data["ID"]+"</td>";
        tr +="<td>"+data["UNITID"]+"</td>";
        tr +="<td>"+data["INSTNM"]+"</td>";
        tr +="<td>"+data["ADDR"]+"</td>";
        tr +="<td>"+data["CITY"]+"</td>";
        tr +="<td>"+data["STABBR"]+"</td>";
        tr +="<td>"+data["ZIP"]+"</td><div></tr>";
        $("#table1").append(tr);
```